# Handling tokens with leading zeros

Tags: python, tokenize

For tokenizing the input expression I'm using `tokenize.generate_tokens()`:

```
tokens = cStringIO.StringIO(SourceLine).readline
tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(tokens)
```

Now, when `SourceLine =  "Y123 = 00911 + 98 / 3"`
in the `tokens` tuple, I'm getting the following token values:

```
"Y123", "=" , "00", "911","+", "98" , "/" , "3"
```

However, when I pass `SourceLine = "Y123 = 00411 + 98 / 3"`, I'm getting:

```
"Y123", "=" , "00411", "+" ,"98","/","3"
```

I did not understand why in the first case for `00911` it generated two tokens `00` and `911` instead of only one token with value `00911`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, integer literals beginning with `0` are interpreted as octal numbers (base 8).  Accordingly, your first `SourceLine` is actually syntactically invalid, because `9` isn't a valid digit in octal:

```
>>> Y123 = 00911 + 98 / 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    Y123 = 00911 + 98 / 3
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

So it seems the tokenizer is parsing it as a valid octal literal beside a decimal literal.  You can post-process this back into the format you want, if you're trying to parse some Python-like language.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that tokenize is interpreting '00411' as an octal number, which '00911' is not. So it is returning '00', a valid octal number, followed by '911', a valid decimal number.